# iphone certain PDFs rendering as black image

Tags: iphone, pdf, ipad

I'm trying to draw the pages of a PDF using the code below.  Some PDF's render correctly, but others simply show as a completely black image, or have partial portions rendered and the rest black.  In comparing what's going on, the ones that show OK seem to have always have "regular" text in them along with some graphics (diagrams, etc.), while the ones that come out black are typically all graphics (like a page of sheet music, for example). Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?
I building this on the new 3.2 SDK.

Thanks!

```
// PDF page drawing expects a Lower-Left coordinate system, so we flip the coordinate system
// before we start drawing.
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
 CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

 // Grab the first PDF page
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myPDF, pageNo);
// We're about to modify the context CTM to draw the PDF page where we want it, so save     the graphics state in case we want to do more drawing
CGContextSaveGState(context);
// CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform provides an easy way to get the transform for a PDF page. It will scale down to fit, including any
// base rotations necessary to display the PDF page correctly. 
CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, true);
// And apply the transform.
CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
// Finally, we draw the page and restore the graphics state for further manipulations!
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Try this out http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGPDFDocumentRef MyGetPDFDocumentRef (const char *filename) {
        CFStringRef path;
        CFURLRef url;
        CGPDFDocumentRef document;
        path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filename,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
        CFRelease (path);
        document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL (url);// 2
        CFRelease(url);
        int count = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages (document);// 3
        if (count == 0) {
            printf("`%s' needs at least one page!", filename);
            return NULL;
        }
        return document;
    }

```
void MyDisplayPDFPage (CGContextRef myContext,size_t pageNumber,const char *filename) {
    CGPDFDocumentRef document;
    CGPDFPageRef page;
    document = MyGetPDFDocumentRef (filename);// 1
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (document, pageNumber);// 2
    CGContextDrawPDFPage (myContext, page);// 3
    CGContextTranslateCTM(myContext, 0, 20);
    CGContextScaleCTM(myContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGPDFDocumentRelease (document);// 4
}



#import "DashBoard.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface UIImage (WBImage)
// rotate UIImage to any angle
-(UIImage*)rotate:(UIImageOrientation)orient;
@end

@implementation UIImage (WBImage)


static inline CGFloat degreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees)
{
    return M_PI * (degrees / 180.0);
}

static inline CGSize swapWidthAndHeight(CGSize size)
{
    CGFloat  swap = size.width;

    size.width  = size.height;
    size.height = swap;

    return size;
}


-(UIImage*)rotate:(UIImageOrientation)orient
{
    CGRect             bnds = CGRectZero;
    UIImage*           copy = nil;
    CGContextRef       ctxt = nil;
    CGRect             rect = CGRectZero;
    CGAffineTransform  tran = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    bnds.size = self.size;
    rect.size = self.size;

    switch (orient)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            return self;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rect.size.width, 0.0);
            tran = CGAffineTransformScale(tran, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rect.size.width,
                                                    rect.size.height);
            tran = CGAffineTransformRotate(tran, degreesToRadians(180.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, rect.size.height);
            tran = CGAffineTransformScale(tran, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            bnds.size = swapWidthAndHeight(bnds.size);
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, rect.size.width);
            tran = CGAffineTransformRotate(tran, degreesToRadians(-90.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            bnds.size = swapWidthAndHeight(bnds.size);
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rect.size.height,
                                                    rect.size.width);
            tran = CGAffineTransformScale(tran, -1.0, 1.0);
            tran = CGAffineTransformRotate(tran, degreesToRadians(-90.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            bnds.size = swapWidthAndHeight(bnds.size);
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rect.size.height, 0.0);
            tran = CGAffineTransformRotate(tran, degreesToRadians(90.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            bnds.size = swapWidthAndHeight(bnds.size);
            tran = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            tran = CGAffineTransformRotate(tran, degreesToRadians(90.0));
            break;

        default:
            // orientation value supplied is invalid
            assert(false);
            return nil;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bnds.size);
    ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    switch (orient)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctxt, -1.0, 1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctxt, -rect.size.height, 0.0);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctxt, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctxt, 0.0, -rect.size.height);
            break;
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(ctxt, tran);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctxt, rect, self.CGImage);

    copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return copy;
}


@end




@implementation DashBoard

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    filePath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"roadie" ofType:@"pdf"]];

    // an IBOutlet UIScrollView
    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(720, 720)];
    // an IBOutlet UIImageView
    [imgV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 720, 720)];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(720, 720));
    // initial page is an size_t variable
    initialPage=1;
    MyDisplayPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), initialPage, [filePath UTF8String],myTable,mainString);
    imgV.image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    imgV.image=[imgV.image rotate:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
}
```

Just copy & paste above code. It will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the background color - specifically, the pdf's I was having trouble with didn't have a white background.  By filling the view with a white rectangle, my problem was solved.